# Gradle/Groovy/Shadow project to create executable jar file

Tags: groovy, gradle, jar

Using this build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
   id 'groovy'
   id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '1.2.2'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.4'
}

version = '0.1'
shadowJar {
    mergeServiceFiles()
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.mycompany.tools.EncodeFile'
    }
}
```

I get an essentially empty .jar file (264 bytes) when I run `~/TOOLS/gradle-2.10/bin/gradle shadowJar`.

I would expect it to contain the groovy.jar and my .class files.

There is some confusion in looking at samples on the web because it seems that plugins { id... } is the new preferred syntax, but the samples are older and do not use that syntax.

The directory structure is:

```
./src/groovy/com/mycompany/tools/EncodeFile.groovy
./build.gradle
```

I would guess that I either have to move my .groovy file, or, I need to modify build.gradle to point to the groovy file.

1. How should I fix this such that that I get a .jar file that will execute like this: `java -jar build/libs/EncodeFile.jar`?
2. Any other tips on using gradle to build self contained .jar files is appreciated.  Both Groovy and Java (and mixed).
3. I will probably be adding third party .jar files that I will want to embed in the executable jar.  Any tips on that would be appreciated as well.

Comment: What is the output from `gradle clean shadowJar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure

```
./src/groovy/com/mycompany/tools/EncodeFile.groovy
```

Should be

```
./src/main/groovy/com/mycompany/tools/EncodeFile.groovy
```

Gradle thinks you have no source code (due to the missing `main` directory)

Also, if you change your gradle file to (adding the application plugin):

```
plugins {
   id 'groovy'
   id 'application'
   id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '1.2.2'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.4'
}

version = '0.1'
mainClassName = 'com.mycompany.tools.EncodeFile'
shadowJar {
    mergeServiceFiles()
}
```

Then you get the same shadowJar functionality, but you also gain `gradle run` to just run the unjarred app

Comment: You won the accepted answer.  For extra credit: why is the jar file named EncodeFile-0.1-all.jar.  The EncodeFile is obvious, the 0.1 is obvious, but why -all?

Comment: Because it's _"all"_ of the classes repackaged into a single jar. Your classes, dependency classes, _all_ of them

Comment: Is shadow doing that for me?  Can I override it?  Of course I can just rename the jar, but I am wondering about the conventions:  Is any .jar file that has other jars inside of it appended with -all?

Comment: Yeah, shadow is doing that. It won't then clash with the output of `gradle jar`. You can just rename it